# What is INT 21H and How Does It Work?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

What is INT 21H and how does it work. Need to do four different functions in assembly 8086 using turbo pascal7. I'd like to know how INT 21H works and how to get system date using AH = 2Bh as i am not sure how this works and cannot find any decent explanations online.

Answer (score 4):

It's the MS-DOS system call. Try the Ralf Brown interrupt list for more information:
http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm

Answer (score 1):

To **get** system date you code

```
mov ah,2Ah
int 21h
```

Now CX holds the year, DH holds the month, DL holds the day and AL holds the day of the week starting with 0=Sunday.

To **set** the date *you* provide the values for CX, DH, and DL

```
mov cx,...
mov dx,...
mov ah,2Bh
int 21h
cmp al,FFh
je InvalidDate
```